Unity: Player Jump Logic Not Working Properly - isGrounded Always True Even When Not on Ground
I’m working on a Unity 3D project and encountering an issue with player jumping. The player can only jump once, and after the first jump, they can’t jump again, even after landing back on the ground. Additionally, the isGrounded condition is always returning true, even when the player is not on the ground.
I’m using a CharacterController and Physics.CheckSphere for ground detection. Below is the code I’m using:
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;         // Movement speed
    public float jumpForce = 10f;     // Jump force
    private bool canJump = true;      // Flag to check if the player can jump

    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 velocity;        // Used to apply gravity and jump force

    public Transform groundCheck;     // Position for ground detection
    public float groundDistance = 0.3f;  // Radius of ground check sphere (adjustable)
    public LayerMask groundMask;      // Layer mask for ground detection

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Ground check using Physics.CheckSphere
        bool isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        // Debugging: Output whether the player is grounded and the position of groundCheck
        Debug.Log("Is Grounded: " + isGrounded + " | GroundCheck Position: " + groundCheck.position);

        // When grounded, reset downward velocity and allow jumping
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (velocity.y < 0)
            {
                velocity.y = -2f;  // Small downward force to keep player grounded
            }
            canJump = true;    // Allow jumping when grounded
        }
        else
        {
            canJump = false;  // Disable jumping when not grounded
        }

        // Player movement
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * moveX + transform.forward * moveZ;
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Jumping logic (only allow jump when grounded)
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && canJump)
        {
            // Apply jump force
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce * -2f * Physics.gravity.y);

            // Disable jumping until grounded again
            canJump = false;
        }

        // Apply gravity to simulate falling
        velocity.y += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // If the player collides with the ground, set canJump to true
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            canJump = true;  // Allow jumping again when touching the ground
        }
    }

    // Visualize the ground check area
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (groundCheck != null)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance);  // Visualize the ground check area
        }
    }
}



Why have both a sphere check and setting canJump also in OnCollisionEnter? The latter is at best redundant

You are using canJump and isGrounded at the same time which can cause confusion. Use just isGrounded and let the player jump when it is true. Also check the ground mask and if the player is not included in it.
